# What movie was Joey talking about in 'The One with the Secret Closet'?

Tags: reference, friends

In the *Friends* episode 'The One with the Secret Closet' (S08E14) Joey describes a movie as having a door behind which no one knows what lies. When it opens, millions of flesh eating bugs come out. What movie is he talking about?

Comment: It's likely the writers made it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all these years I am still uncertain if this is a real movie or something the writers made up. But it always reminds me of the following scene of [Mummy (1999)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mummy_%281999_film%29). Keep in mind that the 8th season of Friends is dated around 2001-2002 so the timing is correct:

Comment: Maybe. There's lots of films with scuttling killer bugs, though and the bit with the "hidden door" doesn't match at all.

Comment: I actually think this is a clever comparison. The part about the door is a bit loose, sure, but if you think about it, they did open a door behind which no one knew what they'd find, and the bugs came out. And with the timing being the same, it's easy the writers could have been inspired by this scene - They could have used anything, and chose bugs; that doesn't seem far-fetched at all.